# Configuration of SqLite and MySql Db in one App.Config

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, sqlite

I got a problem with my db config until now i only used a `MySql`Db in my app. And had the configuration in my App.Config. Everything worked fine. See my app config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
<configSections>
<section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
<!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
</configSections>
<startup>
<supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" />
</startup>
<entityFramework codeConfigurationType="MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlEFConfiguration, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6">
<providers>
  <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6" />
 </providers>
</entityFramework>
<connectionStrings>...</connectionStrins>
<system.data>
  <DbProviderFactories>...</DbProviderFactories>
</system.data>
</configuration>
```

When i add these two `Providers`

```
 <provider invariantName="System.Data.SQLite" type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderServices, System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
  <provider invariantName="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderServices, System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
```

for the new `SqLite` db, they wont be found because of the 
    `codeConfigurationType="MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlEFConfiguration, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6"` Attribute of the `entityFrameWork` knot.

When I leave that attribute the `Sqlite` db works but `MySql`has problems and defining two `entityFramework`knots doesnt work. Does anybody have a solution? Thanks